# New Gui does not accept placement "Right" on a command

Tags: codenameone

I try to add a command on the new Gui with right placement but it adds automatically overflow to the .java file.

The Preview design shows it correct https://gyazo.com/eef78ee9d564c6957e62148db50e6bc4

but the simulator shows as overflowhttps://gyazo.com/a4023a18e48ee19a89bc86e294b5434f

Is it a bug?

Thanks in advance

Comment: gui version 1.17 , plugin version 3.5.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the GUI builder, [we filed a lot of issues](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20guibuilder) so please file this there too. It should work although might require you to go thru the steps again.

I would also suggest looking within the `.gui` file and seeing that the command generation looks correct.

Comment: Yes and fixed and I am waiting the new version. I hope soon. Thank you. Excellent service.

Comment: i upgraded to new version 3.5.7 , i cleaned the project but still the same problem!

Comment: ok, i had to right-click project, open properties, click ok and then worked. You have suggested this solution to another problem, and it worked on this issue now after updating to the new version. Btw the new Gui is getting better and better! Good work

Comment: Thanks! We need to improve the update process so it's a bit smoother, we have a lot of moving parts for each update...